# como meter datos de mysql en una tabla

Tags: php, mysql

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Consultar Ausencias</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h3 style='text-align=center'>Tabla de ausencias</h3>


<?php

    //CONECTARSE A LA BASE DE DATOS
    require_once 'dbconnect.php';

    //SCRIPT DE LA CONSULTA SQL
    $q ="SELECT * FROM h_guardias;";
    //EJECUTAR LA CONSULTA
    $r= mysqli_query($conn,$q);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r))


    {

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<tr>" .$row ['Nombre'] . "</td>";
        echo "<tr>" .$row ['Apellidos'] . "</td>";
        echo "<tr>" .$row ['Motivo'] . "</td>";
        echo "<tr>" .$row ['Dia'] . "</td>";
        echo "<tr>" .$row ['Hora'] . "</td>";
        echo "<tr>" .$row ['Asignatura'] . "</td>";
        echo "<tr>" .$row ['Ejercicios'] . "</td>";
    }
    ?>


<table class="table table-bordered"> 

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nombre </th>
            <th>Apellidos </th>
            <th>Motivo </th>
            <th>Dia </th>
            <th>Hora</th>
            <th>Asignatura</th>
            <th>Ejercicios</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>SELECT*FROM .$row ['Nombre'] . </td>
        </tr>   
    </thead>
    <tbody id= "myTable">
    </tbody>
    </table>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SO Lolai, por favor te recomiendo leer [Como Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y hacer el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funciona el sitio.

Comment: @lolai además de lo que te escribio Federico pudes ampliar mas tu pregunta como por ejemplo que error te esta dando

Answer (score 0):

la informacion que brindas no es la correcta, asi que te mostrare un codigo que realize tomando de la documentacion de php
Desconozco si utilizas PDO o mysli.

```
<?php 
    include_once "conexion.php";
    try {  
      $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

      $pdo->beginTransaction();
      $pdo->exec("insert into users (name, last_name, email, password) values ('Joe', 'Bloggs', 'blog@correo.com','123445')");
      echo "Datos agregados! :)";
      $pdo->commit();

    } catch (Exception $e) {
      $pdo->rollBack();
      echo "Fallo: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

 ?>
```

Claro una vez realizada la conexion lo incluyes en tu proyecto.
en este caso al llamar esta archivo de php, me ejecuta el script.
mi proveerdor de base de datos, en mi caso es Postgresql.
utilizando [PDO](http://php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php).

**DB postgresql**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
puedes buscar mas ejemplos. en la documentacion de php

Espero te ayude.

Answer (score 0):

Estás bien orientado, lo que te falta es cambiar de lugar donde el cuerpo de tus renglones son impresos, la forma genérica de popular una tabla con datos en php sería la siguiente

```
<?php

require_once 'dbconnect.php';

//SCRIPT DE LA CONSULTA SQL
$q = "SELECT * FROM h_guardias;";
//EJECUTAR LA CONSULTA
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $q);
?>
<table class="data-table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Nombre </th>
        <th>Apellidos </th>
        <th>Motivo </th>
        <th>Dia </th>
        <th>Hora</th>
        <th>Asignatura</th>
        <th>Ejercicios</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo '<tr>
                 <td>' . $row ['Nombre'] . '</td>
                 <td>' . $row ['Apellidos'] . '</td>
                 <td>' . $row ['Motivo'] . '</td>
                 <td>' . $row ['Dia'] . '</td>
                 <td>' . $row ['Hora'] . '</td>
                 <td>' . $row ['Asignatura'] . '</td>
                 <td>' . $row ['Ejercicios'] . '</td>
                </tr>';
    } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```